# Spock mock/stub rest api

Tags: mocking, spock, micronaut, stub

I have the following interface in micronaut to perform a HTTP POST request:

```java
@Client("shoppingCenter")
@SubscriptionKey
interface ApiClient {
  @Post("/shoppingcenter/api/Order")
  OrderResponse createResponse(@Body OrderRequest request);
}
```

I have a class which calls the interface:

```java
public class OrderService {
  @Inject
  ApiClient apiClient;

  public void sendNewOrder(String item) {
    OrderRequest request = new OrderRequest.builder() 
    // ..builder code
    OrderResponse response = apiClient.createResponse(request);
  }
}
```

And I would like to mock/stub the API call in my spock test, I have tried this way:

```java
apiClient.createResponse(request) >> new OrderResponse("orderID")
```

```java
class OrderServiceSpec extends ApplicationContextSpecification implements RepositoriesFixture, LeakageDetector {
  @Subject
  @Shared
  OrderService OrderService = applicationContext.getBean(OrderService)

  def 'test "sendNewOrder"' (){
    given: 'Item'
    ApiClient apiClient = Stub()
    OrderRequest request = new OrderRequest();
    apiClient.createResponse(request) >> new OrderResponse("orderID")

    when:
    OrderService.sendNewOrder("someItem")

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()

    cleanup:
    //...
  }
}
```

However I get the error:

```
Expected no exception to be thrown, but got 'io.micronaut.discovery.exceptions.NoAvailableServiceException'

    at spock.lang.Specification.noExceptionThrown(Specification.java:118)
    at com.daimler.api.notification.NotificationServiceSpec.test "sendNewOrder"(OrderServiceSpec.groovy:46)
Caused by: io.micronaut.discovery.exceptions.NoAvailableServiceException: No available services for ID: shopping-center
    at io.micronaut.http.client.loadbalance.AbstractRoundRobinLoadBalancer.getNextAvailable(AbstractRoundRobinLoadBalancer.java:50)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$1.doOnNext(Publishers.java:214)
```

Comment: If you test sendNewOrder, apiClient should be a mock, and then you decide what the call to createResponse(request) returns.
not sure what you mean by applying for a API call.

Comment: What is your question? What is not working? And where does the `any()` come from? Are you migrating from JUnit + Mockito to Spock? You should rather use `apiClient.createResponse(_)`. Moreover, I cannot see where you inject `apiClient` into `OrderService`. The service of course only uses the mock if you inject it, so it knows about it. In general, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than incomplete code snippets which leave people speculating. We cannot debug what we cannot see, and what you think is essential is not necessarily where the problem really is.

Comment: @kriegaex my question is, how I can mock an api call. (the any() is wrong, i thought i could use as mockito, I have updated the code). I have updated the code, so I can be clearer to understand

Comment: @TidharKleinOrbach yes, that's my question, how I can mock the apiClient in Spock

Comment: how do you inject the apiClient to OrderService?
perhaps this is what you want: https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/module_spring.html#_using_code_springbean_code

Comment: @TidharKleinOrbach , in my test class (OrderServiceSpec) I want to mock ApiClient. I looked at the link you shared, '@SpringBean' applies for Spring boot cases, however I am using micronaut, is there another alternative?

Comment: Creating a mock is not enough, you must wire it into the target class in order for it to make use of it. I am confident that Micronaut (which I never used before) has documentation explaining how to wire dependencies into services. Maybe it even has its own testing support. Just use it from Spock as you would from JUnit, TestNG or whatever testing tool they describe there.

Comment: When you edit a question - I just noticed by coincidence - please notify others by a comment. There are not notifications for question or answer edits. Besides, why did you intentionally remove the syntax highlighting I added to your previous version? Now your code is harder to read. I am going to add it again for everyone's benefit.

Comment: I am sorry, I was not aware that you added more syntax, thank you for adding it

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should read some basic Micronaut documentation, e.g. [Micronaut Test - Testing with Spock](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#spock), especially section "Using Spock Mocks". Like I said in my comment, I never used Micronaut before. But I was able to find this within 10 seconds by googling `micronaut test mock`.

Comment: yes, I look at the docu, but I am more confused, because the example I have it uses a declarative http client, but I didn't find any implementation of the interface. Should I create an implementation class, but what I should have as body... I am reading about the topic, because I am confused